# How do I declare typedef in Swift

Tags: typedef, swift, ios8

If I require a custom type in Swift, that I could `typedef`, how do I do it? (Something like a closure syntax typedef)

Comment: Apple being Apple (~different~), their typedef is called `typealias`. Have you read Apple's *Swift Programming Language* yet?

Comment: You can also find this document online here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/ (rather than include a direct link that might break just search for "Swift Programming Language" on the page)

Comment: @Kreiri Swift's `typealias` is not called `typedef` because its capability is far less than that of `typedef`, and far more focused on the use-cases needed in modern programming.  This follows the general design principle of Swift to have a larger lexicon focused towards specific needs, unlike C's small lexicon meant to be combined in… _creative_… ways.  If Apple had chose to call it `typedef`, people would expect it to work like C's `typedef`.  That's the design issue Microsoft runs into frequently— they'll use established names but have their implementation work differently.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The keyword `typealias` is used in place of `typedef`:

```swift
typealias CustomType = String
var customString: CustomType = "Test String"
```

Comment: how can i make a new type of this closure                 let completionBlock:(NSString, NSError!) ->Void = {strg,error in
    myString = "Haider"
    println("My text:\(myString)")
}

Comment: typealias newClosure = ((strg1:NSString,num1:NSNumber)->Void)?

Comment: @WaqasHaiderSheikh You can do like `typealias closureType = (NSString, NSError!) ->Void`. And use it as `let completionBlock:closureType = {strg,error in  //do something}`

Answer (score 16):

added to the answer above:

**"typealias" is the keyword used is swift which does similar function as typedef.**

```
    /*defines a block that has 
     no input param and with 
     void return and the type is given 
     the name voidInputVoidReturnBlock*/        
    typealias voidInputVoidReturnBlock = () -> Void

    var blockVariable :voidInputVoidReturnBlock = {

       println(" this is a block that has no input param and with void return")

    }
```

**To create a typedef with input param the syntax is as shown below :**

```
    /*defines a block that has 
     input params NSString, NSError!
    and with void return and the type 
    is given the name completionBlockType*/ 
    typealias completionBlockType = (NSString, NSError!) ->Void

    var test:completionBlockType = {(string:NSString, error:NSError!) ->Void in
        println("\(string)")

    }
    test("helloooooooo test",nil);
    /*OUTPUTS "helloooooooo test" IN CONSOLE */
```