# How to define block in Swift like in Objective-C?

Tags: swift, block

In ObjectiveC i can define block which will be used many places like

```
typedef void (^APISuccessHandler)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result);
```

and then use it in (for example) ViewController propery

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) APISuccessHandler successHandler;
```

How do same in swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077428/how-do-i-declare-typedef-in-swift for how to typedef, http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/ for swift block syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `typealias`

```
typealias MyType=(str:String,num:Int)->()
```

Then,

```
var test:MyType = {(str,num) in
    println(str)
    println(num)
}
```

Execute the block

```
  test(str: "123", num: 1)
```

Output

```
123
1
```