# Trying to convert objective-c to swift and couldnt solve an issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am trying to convert an objective-c project to swift2

`typedef void (^PDFCMapParserHandler)(NSArray *lines);`

can someone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077428/how-do-i-declare-typedef-in-swift

Comment: this is wrong. i know that typealias can be used. but the main problem was, i could not convert exactly this: typedef void (^PDFCMapParserHandler)(NSArray *lines); to typealias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I want to convert set of codes from ObjC to Swift, I use this
[link](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code) which is much easier than banging my head.

To simply answer your question:
`var PDFCMapParserHandler` or `var PDFCMapParserHandler = NSArray()`