# swift equivalent for typedef

Tags: ios, swift

In C language I would write something like :

```
    typedef struct old new;
struct old
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};
```

I cannot find the equivalent in swift.

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I declare typedef in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077428/how-do-i-declare-typedef-in-swift)

Comment: In this situation you wouldn't need a `typedef` in Swift. You would just declare a `struct`.

Comment: I am just giving an example to use the typedef the same way, of course it isn't necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift it will look like this :

```
typealias new = old

struct old {
    let x = 0
    let y = 0
}
```

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com whats the issue if someone answer the question. if its duplicate flag it as duplicate but downvoting correct answer is not a good approach

Comment: @jawadAli you got it wrong. I was pointing him that this question already has an answer. Also, i didnt downvote, i just shared the link. Someone else downvoted.

Comment: okay ... sorry for miss understanding :)

Comment: @jawadAli No worries. It's risky to comment on downvoted posts ;) People misunderstand.

Comment: haha you are right :)

Comment: @jawadAli Yeah I just gave him the answer which is true, I don't understand the downvoting, It's not my fault if the answer was easy to find, I just wanted to help

Comment: Yeah same thing i was saying ... dont know who try to demotivate others

Answer (score 1):

**"typealias" is the keyword used is swift which does similar function as typedef.**

```
typealias MLAnimationCompletionBlock = (_ finished: Bool) -> Void

var blockVariable : MLAnimationCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (finished: Bool) -> Void in

       println(" this is a block that has bool input param and with void return")

    }
```